# Does Flutter have standard built-in themes, except the default theme?

Tags: flutter, material-ui, themes

Does Flutter have standard built-in themes, except the default theme?
Maybe other Material colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two themes built in as Light and Dark themes. The default theme is Light.

There are several material colors but if that's not enough you can generate your own color palette and theme based on the colors you want.

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question. I thought as severel Material Colors are "built-in" (e.g. Colors.cyan.shade200) maybe more themes are built-in.